# WinRT CertificateEnrollmentManager.InstallCertificateAsync errors out

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, x509certificate

I am trying to install x509 certificate (pragmatically) on UWP (Universal Windows App) using javascript (WinRT).

```
    public step(): void {
    let options: any = window.Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.InstallOptions.none;
    try {
        window.Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateEnrollmentManager
            .installCertificateAsync(this.x509, options)
            .done((resp: any) => {
                console.log(resp);
            });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Certificate looks as follows:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

However the code errors out with following message.

```
//# sourceURL=browsertools://browsertools.library.js

(function() { return function(err) { var o = {};o["Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction"] = function () { o["WinRT Promise.done()"](); };o["WinRT Promise.done()"] = function () { throw err; };return o["Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction"]}})()

WinRTError: The data is invalid.

InstallResponse
   at o[WinRT Promise.done()] (eval code:1:175)
   at o[Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction] (eval code:1:10
```

Any idea?

Comment: How did you generate the certificate(x509)?

Comment: Its generated at server side (outside of my control)

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with this Certificate.Here is the document of [InstallCertificateAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificateenrollmentmanager.installcertificateasync). Check the Remarks section. Is the certificate generated through the workflow(CreateRequestAsync->submit request to server->get certificate from response)?

Comment: Yes I am generating the CreateRequestAsync on same PC and storing it in a variable as string. Then send this csr to server which returns X509 which I store in another variable. Then use this (x509) in InstallCertificateAsync.